# How to display line number for a row in a file from Spark read?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am interested in performing a spark.read("path/*.tsv") to read all data text files (ex: tsv in this case) from a given path.

When displaying an arbitrary query result to the console, is it possible to add a column indicating the actual line number in which the row appears in the file? For example if the row appeared on line 10 from the file abc.tsv, I would like to see '10' appear as the value in the column.

There is an API to provide the file name which a row originates from, but I am also interested in the line number that it appears in the file. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: You would need to have the line numbers in the files themselves.  You could calculate a row number, but it would be really expensive, and probably meaningless due to the data and processing being distributed.

Comment: I think this is very hard to get after spark loads the data, the ordering is not guaranteed. I  think the better solution would be to add a line number to your CSV files before reading with a spark. You can write short scripts to add a row number to all the files.